# VSE modifier affects alpha

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a png image sequence with alpha. When I try to use a modifier on it to adjust brightness/color it affects the whole image. It brightens the transparent parts where it's empty. So the background strip becomes brighter as well. Even if I try to render it without the background, the parts where it's transparent/empty have data now. Why are modifiers affecting alpha? Shouldn't they be just adjusting color where there's no alpha? How can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm sorry, would you mind showing at least your settings in the VSE and the modifier? Or maybe upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com to check it out? And which Blender version you are using? In my Blender it works just as expected, the background strip is not affected by the modifier.